# Why does my gulp src ignore exclusions made with "!"

Tags: gulp

My gulp script is ignoring my not exclusions in the src.

```
gulp.src([
  srcPath + name + '/.env', 
  srcPath + name + '/**/bin/*', 
  '!' + srcPath + name + '/dist', 
  srcPath + name + '/node_modules', 
  srcPath + name + '/**/*.js', 
  '!' + srcPath + name + '/config'
])
```

But it is still including the srcPath + name + '/dist' files, even though I that that marking a path with the ! excludes files.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `!` last, and it will work (this is one of the most counter intuitive things i have ever seen).   I'm assuming `srcPath` and `name` are correct.

```
gulp.src([
  srcPath + name + '/.env', 
  srcPath + name + '/**/bin/*', 
  srcPath + name + '/node_modules', 
  srcPath + name + '/**/*.js',
  '!' + srcPath + name + '/dist', 
  '!' + srcPath + name + '/config'

])
```

Comment: hmm even with that change it's still copying over the /dist folder, since I'm piping the src to `.pipe(gulp.dest(srcPath + name + '/dist/'))` ... thus it creates a recursive dist folder inside the destination dist, e.g. dist/dist .. I think the  **/*.js is taking precedence